# Google Maps (Javascript API): Markers toggle between Icon and Label?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I know we can do some stuffs on Markers upon some events, like:

```
// var markers: stored somewhere above

map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {

    /**
     * After if/else checking zoom_level , etc
     * then:
     */
    markers.forEach(function(marker){

        marker.setOptions({
            label: {
                text: 'Something else',
                color: '#ff0000',
            }
        }); //Change label text/color etc
        marker.setIcon(url); //Change Icon

    });
});
```

But how to I actually properly **"hide" the Marker Icon (it's "Icon" only, not the entire Marker)** please? So that I could only show Label alone. (Toggling between Marker **Icons vs Labels**, based on situations)

I tried all those below, but doesn't really work:

```
marker.setIcon(null);
marker.setIcon('');
marker.setIcon(' ');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
marker.setIcon({
    scale: <int>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a **custom marker icon** as you can scale the icon, which won't scale the label.

Zoom in and out in the below snippet to see the behavior.

```js
var marker;

function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoomControl: true
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    label: 'HELLO WORLD',
  });

  setIconWithScale(marker, 0);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

    if (map.getZoom() >= 6) {

      setIconWithScale(marker, 1);

    } else {

      setIconWithScale(marker, 0);
    }
  });
}

function setIconWithScale(marker, scale) {

  marker.setIcon({
    path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    strokeWeight: 0,
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(0, 30),
    scale: scale
  });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize">
</script>
```

Another option would be to change the icon `fillOpacity` if you need to use `labelOrigin` and don't want to see the label jump when changing the scale of the icon.

Comment: So it's basically all about `marker.setIcon({scale: int})` is it?

Comment: Set the scale to zero, or as I said, change the opacity. What's your question really? I gave you a full working code snippet as an example.

Comment: So again, it's all just about playing around either `marker.setIcon({scale: ...})` or `marker.setIcon({opacity: ...})`. I don't think the rest are relevant to the question anyway. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: The rest is for you to click "Run code snippet" and see the results. That's called a good quality answer. When an answer helped, people here usually up-vote and/or accept it.

Comment: @夏期劇場 no further feedback? Don't want to accept my answer?